# jQuery AJAX request to fetch HTML is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am learning jQuery and REST webservices. Below code returns the HTML response from rest webservice which I have creates using rest jersey.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "<h1>Hello Jersey</h1>";
    }
}
```

When I hit the URL in the browser it gives me the below result as expected:

> Hello Jersey

Now, I want to consume the same HTMl response in my jquery, but I am not getting the expected result.
The alert shows me error status. Please see the jquery code, please help me resolve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/RestTest/rest/hello/",
    success:function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    },
    dataType:"html",
    error:function(request,status,exception) {
        alert(status);
    },
    complete:function(request,status) {alert("CALL Complete>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+status)}
    });
  });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual response from the server?  What's the error?

Comment: `exception` in the `error` handler will contain at least PART of the server's error message. output that as well as in your alert. it'll probably give you a better idea of what's wrong than just the status code.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your quick reply.I trid to alert the exception it is showing "No Transport"

Comment: @Ashu Just curious is it necessary to use datatype as `HTML` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that the URL you are calling is incorrect.

your url ends with `rest/hello/` the last `/` makes this a different url to `rest/hello` so the route won't be found.

Try changing your URL to: `RestTest/rest/hello` - or the equivalent relative URL to your page, just chop off the trailing `/`.

Also - is the rest service on the same domain as the site? I.E is your site located at `http://localhost:8080/`?  If not, it may be a cross domain issue - hard to tell without knowing the full error message.

Comment: I changed to RestTest/rest/hello and tested, but no success same error.

Comment: And the domain? did you remove `http://localhost:8080/` from your url? - make sure that the URL you are using is relative to the page you're running it on. - try `/RestTest/rest/hello` - not sure what the `@path` attribute is on your service - is that the route? so should the url be `/hello` ?

Comment: I am running the webservice project in tomcat6.0 and my html file is outside of this project.

Comment: Thanks Daren, based on the questions you asked I figured it out. It might be the domain issue. So, I copied my html to same project and tested and update the url as you said /RestTest/rest/hello. It worked...Thanks a lot for the guidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to force a `crossDomain` request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true.

[Read This](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"http://localhost:8080/RestTest/rest/hello/",
    crossDomain: true,  
    success:function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    },
    dataType:"html",
    error:function(request,status,exception) {
        alert(status);
    },
    complete:function(request,status) {alert("CALL Complete>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+status)}
    });
  });
  });
```

Comment: Hello Suraj, thanks for extending help. I will try as you suggested.